# How do i ping websites in Python?

Tags: python, network-programming, ping

I need to find a way to ping automatically every website i enter on a daily basis, every day i need to do a list with every site the device got in and the ping, the ping format is ICMP

i have tried this but i dont know how to do the part where its done with every site i enter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WkOr.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316866/ping-a-site-in-python) answer your question?

Comment: thanks for helping but every site(IP) is manually put in the code,, is there any way of detecting the website(or their IP) and ping it automatically?

Comment: is there some type of criteria to determine what websites you need to ping? do you know what they are ahead of time?

Comment: its for testing network traffic in general, every website counts(youtube, google ), just for testing if there are network problems

Comment: are you saying you want to ping every website on the internet? if you just need to test, for example twenty sites to check your connection, just put the ip address those sites into your script.

Comment: Sorry if im not explaining myself, i recently started programing, but yeah that could work,, do u know other post or guides i could use related to this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want list of  webpages visited with `Chrome` or `Firefox` then they should keep history in some SQLite file. And Python has standard module `sqlite3`

Comment: [Google chrome history sqlite - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307673/google-chrome-history-sqlite)